# include module in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am a starter with ruby, I searched that if someone else has asked similar question but was not able to find any. so I am asking it here.

I am trying my hand at modules in ruby.

I created a folder Project

inside Project folder, created a class One

```
class Project::One

  include Project::Rest

end
```

inside Project folder, created a module Rest

```
module Project::Rest

 def display
   puts "in display"
 end

end
```

but when I try to run the program(ruby one.rb) I get the

uninitialized constant Project (NameError)

Please help me

Comment: Fyi, when you're happy with an answer, you should tag it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you never actually define the `Project` constant. You have to define it before you can use it. Example:

```
# root.rb
module Project
end
require "project/test"

# project/test.rb
class Project::Test
end
```

You should then be able to run `ruby root.rb`. Another approach is to state the module in the namespace.

```
# root.rb
require "project/test"

# project/test.rb
module Project
  class Test
  end
end
```

With this example, you are able to run `ruby project/test.rb` as well, since the `Project` module is defined in that file.

And if you have multiple files defining the `Project` module, that's not a problem either. It won't be re-defined, it will always be the same module.

Both of these methods will define the `Project` module. Simply going `Project::Test` will not, however, define the module.

As a sidenote, Rails has a auto loader. If you're in a rails app, and use a certain folder structure, these kind of intermediate modules will be defined for you. Without Rails, though, you have to define them yourself.

Comment: thanx for your reply...now I understand what I was doing wrong....your side note was very helpful as I had seen the same work in rails application

Comment: This answer is correct. However, the two below answers are correct as well, and perhaps more in keeping with the example given in the question. Could whoever down-voted Mipadi and Alex's answers perhaps explain why? I think it is misleading that they have negative scores since they work, and the difference is mainly one of style and application layout (which wasn't clear from the question).

Comment: The down-votes were from me. I actually tried to retract them because I came to the same conclusion as you, but it was too late. Apparently, you can only retract a vote shortly after you voted.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not nesting your classes/modules correctly. You have to declare a module with the `module` keyword, not merely by writing `class Project::Class`. Assuming you have this structure:

```
Project/
    one.rb
    rest.rb
```

then your files should look something like this:

```
# one.rb
require 'rest'

module Project
  class One
    include Project::Rest
  end
end

# rest.rb
module Project
  module Rest
    def display
      puts 'in display'
    end
  end
end
```

Note how the modules are nested in these examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you have code in multiple files, you have to load those files before you can access what's in them. This is usually done with a `require` statement. I think what you want to do should look like this:

```
# one.rb
require 'rest'
module Project
  class One
    include Rest
  end
end


# rest.rb
module Project
  module Rest
    def display
      puts "in display"
    end
  end
end
```